# MS ToDo API is giving error for few users in Taskfolders Endpoint

Tags: outlook-restapi, microsoft-todo

MS ToDo API is giving error for few users when using following endpoint :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/taskfolders
```

Here is the piece of code :

```
$accessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6I*******sYVg0X0";
$url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/taskfolders";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken)
));
$output=curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the error which I am getting :

```
stdClass Object (
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => ErrorItemNotFound
        [message] => The specified object was not found in the store.
    )

 )
```

As per the documentation of MS, we should get the list of default folder.

[Here is the MS documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#TaskFolderResource)

That means, I should get default folder list in response and which I am getting in case of other users.
I checked the token validity, it is alive.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: In case if you're talking about shared tasks then it's not supported at this point. I remember an user voice on this - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40295248-get-shared-task-folders-using-graph-api. You may want to vote for it, so that Microsoft can consider for it.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're talking about shared tasks then it's not supported at this point. I remember an user voice on this - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40295248-get-shared-task-folders-using-graph-api. You may want to vote for it, so that Microsoft can consider for it